# I need a daily cooldown for each user in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

im making a credits command but everyone can user `daily` command everytime so i need a cooldown for each user, if i did a daily cooldown for all users then one user can use `daily`/day here is my code:

```py
    @client.command()
    async def daily(ctx):
        await open_account(ctx.author)
        users = await get_bank_data()
        user = ctx.author
        earning = random.randrange(101)
        await ctx.send(f":dollar: Daily wallet has been claimed! You got: **{earning}$**")
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earning
        with open('./bank.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users,f)
```

Comment: Hi, SO is not a site where you can say "I need this functionality in my code" expecting someone else to write it for you. Give it a shot yourself & ask questions when you have problems. To get you going - I see you're already using `json` files to store data so you could use something similar to store when the user last claimed his daily. Implementing this is up to you though, we're not just going to give you a working piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method to exclude a user from a command for 24 hours would be to use [cooldowns](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown).

***All you need to do is implement the following:***

```py
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType

@commands.cooldown(1, 86400, BucketType.user)
```

The second number specifies the seconds so you can execute the command every 24 hours.

**Note** that if the bot restarts the cooldown is gone!

Answer (score 0):

**Use the code below if you want to make a cooldown on a command for each user:**

```
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.cooldown(1, 86400, commands.BucketType.user)
```

If you want to make a cooldown, simply use this BucketType according to what you want:

- user
- guild
- channel
- member
- category
- role